# Who really controls the area behind the Sahara wall

Tags: north-africa

I would like to know who really controls [this blank area which is possessed by Morocco and behind the sahara wall](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=8/23.221/-12.607), it's controlled by the moroccan army or by the polisario ? or it's blank area controlled by none of them because it doesn't contain any city or form of civilization ?

Comment: Probably better suited for another stack. Maybe [Politics.SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: i don't think that is a political issue, i'm just wanting to know what happens in that area

Comment: Is the Sahara Wall the same as the "Moroccan Wall?"

Comment: This is a politics question, and [**a trivial one**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Zone_(region)) at that. The [Polisario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polisario_Front) controls it.